# Plugin of Multiple buffers in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I hope to create a plugin to do multiple buffers in QGIS. This is my script:

```py
"""/***************************************************************************
 izisse_test
                                 A QGIS plugin
 test of plugin
                              -------------------
        begin                : 2014-06-11
        copyright            : (C) 2014 by Hakima ELCHAHLAFI
        email                : hakima.elchahlafi@gmail.com
 ***************************************************************************/

/***************************************************************************
 *                                                                         *
 *   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify  *
 *   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by  *
 *   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or     *
 *   (at your option) any later version.                                   *
 *                                                                         *
 ***************************************************************************/"""

# Import the PyQt and QGIS libraries
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
import resources_rc
# Import the code for the dialog
from izisse_testdialog import izisse_testDialog
import os.path

class izisse_test:

    def __init__(self, iface):
        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface
        # initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = QFileInfo(QgsApplication.qgisUserDbFilePath()).path() + "/python/plugins/izisse_test"
        # initialize locale
        localePath = ""
        locale = QSettings().value("locale/userLocale").toString()[0:2]

        if QFileInfo(self.plugin_dir).exists():
            localePath = self.plugin_dir + "/i18n/izisse_test_" + locale + ".qm"

        if QFileInfo(localePath).exists():
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(localePath)

            if qVersion() > '4.3.3':
                QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

        # Create the dialog (after translation) and keep reference
        self.dlg = izisse_testDialog()

    def initGui(self):
        # Create action that will start plugin configuration
        self.action = QAction(
            QIcon(":/plugins/izisse_test/icon.png"),
            u"...........", self.iface.mainWindow())
        # connect the action to the run method
        QObject.connect(self.action, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.run)

        # Add toolbar button and menu item
        self.iface.addToolBarIcon(self.action)
        self.iface.addPluginToMenu(u"&izisse", self.action)

    def unload(self):
        # Remove the plugin menu item and icon
        self.iface.removePluginMenu(u"&izisse", self.action)
        self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.action)

    # run method that performs all the real work
    def run(self):
        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result == 1:
            # do something useful (delete the line containing pass and
            # substitute with your code)
            self.one = self.dlg.one.value()
            self.two = self.dlg.two.value()
            self.layer = self.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
            self.selected = self.layer.selectedFeatures()
            self.crs = self.layer.crs()

            ladistance = self.two

            for houba in range(0, self.one):

                # Create a memory layer for storing the results
                resultl = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:4326", "result" + str(ladistance), "memory")
            resultl.setCrs(self.crs) 
                resultpr = resultl.dataProvider()

            featuresScaled = []

                for coin in self.selected:
                coin.setGeometry(coin.geometry().buffer(self.distance,5))
                    featuresScaled.append(coin)
            
                ladistance = ladistance + self.distance

                self.iface.mainWindow().statusBar().showMessage("Adding features to results layer")
                resultpr.addFeatures(featuresScaled)
                QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(resultl)

#            self.message = self.nbbufstr + " buffers requested with distance " + self.distancestr + " on the layer " + self.layer.name() + " for " + nbselect + " selected features"

            
#       QMessageBox.information(self.iface.mainWindow(), QCoreApplication.translate('title', "Info"), QCoreApplication.translate('themessage', self.message))
```

When I try to in QQGIS like a new plugin i have this message error in line 83

```py
self.one = self.dlg.one.value()
AttributeError: 'izisse_testDialog' object has no attribute 'one'
```

Can you tell what is the problem and how I can solve it?

This is my izisse_testdialog script

```py
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from ui_izisse_test import Ui_izisse_test
# create the dialog for zoom to point


class izisse_testDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        self.ui = Ui_izisse_test()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the error you will notice that it occured in your `izisse_testDialog` file which you did not post.

My guess is that is ether a typo or a missing reference to `self.one`. By any means this is rather a programming question and not about GIS.

Comment: its my code of  izisse_testdialog  :
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from ui_izisse_test import Ui_izisse_test
# create the dialog for zoom to point 



class izisse_testDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        self.ui = Ui_izisse_test()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)